# Are moderators allowed to migrate question from MSO to SO?

Tags: discussion

Are moderators allowed to migrate question from MSO to SO? Can I migrate question from other meta sites to MSO?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a question is asked on MSO but belongs on a site-specific meta, we can send it over if appropriate.

We can migrate from MSO to SO, but we choose not to, for the simple reason that most programming questions that get posted here are the result of users getting lost or banned, and are almost always of low quality and not worth migrating. For the occasional hidden gem, it's better that the author learn which site it's appropriate to post to, so instead of migrating we teach them what to do and send them on their way.

I don't speak for mods of other sites, but I'm sure they don't migrate from meta to main either for the same reason.

Comment: Are users with more than 3k reputation also can vote for migration from meta sites? and can users with 250 reputation, vote for migration of their own question?

Comment: No, there are no pre-defined migration paths from MSO (or any other meta) to any other site, @Sangeeta. As a general rule, if you're posting an off-topic question here we want you to slow down and read things before you go any further.

Comment: In other words: Just because it's posted on Meta doesn't mean we stop following the "don't migrate crap" rule.